# React-Router Client-Side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hi I'm new to React and having a bit of trouble with client-side routing.

I've seen in places that you can use react-router without a server instance like express or simple-server serving up the static files, but when I try to put something together I get this error:

`[react-router] Location "/Users/<user>/Desktop/webapp-client/dist/index.html" did not match any routes`

I would like to host the site as a static site e.g. Amazon S3 and cloudfront and connect to an NodeJS Express backend. I've seen that Angular 2 can route without having a server instance.

Could someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely right. If you will read [this tutorial about react-router](https://www.kirupa.com/react/creating_single_page_app_react_using_react_router.htm), you can realize that all files are static.

So problem is not in react-router, it is somewhere else (Amazon S3, NodeJS Express backend, etc.)

Comment: awesome! appreciate the link. The tutorial looks pretty good so I'll go through it :)